# Вызов serivce каждые n секунд

Tags: java, android

Не могу до конца понять как сделать что бы мой IntentService вызывался каждые N секунд и делал определенный действия в бекраудне. Нагуглил такой код:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60, pintent);
```

Этот код я вызываю в методе onCreate моей основной активити. Но он почему то не работает. Как правильно это реализовать?

Update: насколько будет правильный такой код?

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActiviy.this, myService.class);
            startService(mServiceIntent);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
        }
    };
    handler.post(refresh);
```

Comment: У вас сервис в манифесте прописан?

Comment: да, если просто startService(mServiceIntent); то работает

Comment: Вы уверены что вам необходимо вызывать Service каждые n-секунд, или же надо чтобы он всегда работал на фоне и выполнял какую-то функцию каждые n-секунд?

Comment: Мне нужно каждый 4 часа слать запрос на мой сервер и вслучае изминение записывать это в бд телефона. Так что вы правы.

Comment: Тогда вызывайте вашу службу при запуске приложения startService(mServiceIntent). В службе регистрируйте pendingIntent AlarmManager.setRepeating с интервалом 4 часа. И уже в broadcastReceiver-е вызывайте вашу функцию.